# issue in executing scikit-learn linear regression model

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a dataset the sample structure of which looks like this:

```
SV,Arizona,618,264,63,923
SV,Arizona,367,268,94,138
SV,Arizona,421,268,121,178
SV,Arizona,467,268,171,250
SV,Arizona,298,270,62,924
SV,Arizona,251,272,93,138
SV,Arizona,215,276,120,178
SV,Arizona,222,279,169,250
SV,Arizona,246,279,64,94
SV,Arizona,181,281,97,141
SV,Arizona,197,286,125.01,182
SV,Arizona,178,288,175.94,256
SV,California,492,208,63,923
SV,California,333,210,94,138
SV,California,361,213,121,178
SV,California,435,217,171,250
SV,California,222,215,62,92
SV,California,177,218,93,138
SV,California,177,222,120,178
SV,California,156,228,169,250
SV,California,239,225,64,94
SV,California,139,229,97,141
SV,California,198,234,125,182
```

The records are in order of `company_id,state,profit,feature1,feature2,feature3`.

Now I wrote this code which breaks he whole dataset into chunks of 12 records (for each company and for each state in that company there are 12 records) and then passes it to `process_chunk()` function. Inside `process_chunk()` the records in the chunk are processed and broken into `test set` and `training set` with record number `10` and `11` going into `test set` while rest going into `training set`. I also store the `company_id` and `state` of records in `test set` into a global list for future display of predicted values. I also append the predicted values to a global list `final_prediction`

Now the issue that I am facing is that `company_list`, `state_list` and `test_set` lists have the same size (of about 200 records) but `final_prediction` has size half of what other lists have (100) records. If the test_set list has size of 200 then shouldn't the `final_prediction` be also of size 200? My current code is:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import csv

final_prediction = []
company_list = []
state_list = []

def process_chunk(chuk):

    training_set_feature_list = []
    training_set_label_list = []
    test_set_feature_list = []
    test_set_label_list = []
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

    prediction_list = []


    # to divide into training & test, I am putting line 10th and 11th in test set
    count = 0
    for line in chuk:
        # Converting strings to numpy arrays
        if count == 9:   
            test_set_feature_list.append(np.array(line[3:4],dtype = np.float))
            test_set_label_list.append(np.array(line[2],dtype = np.float))
            company_list.append(line[0])
            state_list.append(line[1])

        elif count == 10:
            test_set_feature_list.append(np.array(line[3:4],dtype = np.float))
            test_set_label_list.append(np.array(line[2],dtype = np.float))
            company_list.append(line[0])
            state_list.append(line[1])

        else:    
            training_set_feature_list.append(np.array(line[3:4],dtype = np.float))
            training_set_label_list.append(np.array(line[2],dtype = np.float))
        count += 1
    # Create linear regression object
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    # Train the model using the training sets
    regr.fit(training_set_feature_list, training_set_label_list)



    prediction_list.append(regr.predict(test_set_feature_list))
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})
    for items in prediction_list:
        final_prediction.append(items)




# Load and parse the data
file_read = open('data.csv', 'r')

reader = csv.reader(file_read)

chunk, chunksize = [], 12

for i, line in enumerate(reader):
    if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
        process_chunk(chunk)
        del chunk[:]
    chunk.append(line)

# process the remainder

#process_chunk(chunk)


print len(company_list)
print len(test_set_feature_list)
print len(final_prediction)
```

Why is this difference in size coming and what mistake am I doing here in my code that I can rectify (maybe something that I am doing very naively and can be done in better way)?

Comment: why don't you use pandas? It has chunking support in the csv reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
prediction_list.append(regr.predict(test_set_feature_list))
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})
for items in prediction_list:
    final_prediction.append(items)
```

`prediction_list` will be a list of arrays (since `predict` returns an array).

So you'll be appending arrays to your `final_prediction`, which is probably what messes up your count: `len(final_prediction)` will probably be equal to the number of chunks.

At this point, the lengths are ok if `prediction_list` has the same length as `test_set_feature_list`.

You probably want to use `extend` like this:

```
final_prediction.extend(regr.predict(test_set_feature_list))
```

Which is also easier to read.

Then the length of `final_prediction` should be fine, and it should be a single list, rather than a list of lists.

Comment: my mistake. it was a type which I have corrected. the `test_set_feature_list ` has the feature records on which the prediction is done once the model is build.

Comment: also I am appending prediction results to `final_predicton` because the `process_chunk()` is called for every 12 records in the dataset. So if I had done `final_prediction = regr.predict(test_set_feature_list)` wouldn't `final_prediction` contain prediction result for the last run of `process_chunk()`?

Comment: when I print my `final_prediction` list I see output as `[array([93495052.969556, 98555123.061462]), array([1000976814.605984, 998276347.359732]),.....]`. What does two values in each array() mean?